# Array is printing only last item recycler view

Tags: arrays, json, kotlin

I have a response which is shown below i want to print the values of array from the Quetions array.I am able to only print the last value.
Please help..

JSON

```
 [
 {
"id": 66,
"module_id": 1,
"module_name": "Medical",
"parent_id": 14,
"label": "Burns ",
"description": null,
"img_id": null,
"questions": [
  {
    "question": "Take a picture",
    "input_type": "text",
    "symptom_id": 66,
    "question_id": 294,
    "symptom_name": "Burns ",
    "input_type_data": null
  },
  {
    "question": "Give an accurate description of the accident",
    "input_type": "text",
    "symptom_id": 66,
    "question_id": 295,
    "symptom_name": "Burns ",
    "input_type_data": null
  },
  {
    "question": "What caused the burns?",
    "input_type": "button",
    "symptom_id": 66,
    "question_id": 296,
    "symptom_name": "Burns ",
    "input_type_data": [
      {
        "text": "Fire"
      },
      {
        "text": "Scorching-metal"
      },
      {
        "text": "Boiling-water"
      },
      {
        "text": "Steams-or-vapours"
      },
      {
        "text": "Sunbeams"
      },
      {
        "text": "Other-agents"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "question": "How long did the exposure last?",
    "input_type": "text",
    "symptom_id": 66,
    "question_id": 297,
    "symptom_name": "Burns ",
    "input_type_data": null
  },
  {
    "question": "Did he inhale boiling gas or vapours?",
    "input_type": "button",
    "symptom_id": 66,
    "question_id": 298,
    "symptom_name": "Burns ",
    "input_type_data": [
      {
        "text": "Yes"
      },
      {
        "text": "Noo"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "symptom_id": 66,
    "question_id": 299,
    "symptom_name": "Burns ",
    "input_type_data": [
      {
        "text": "Conscious"
      },
      {
        "text": "Unconscious"
      }
    ],
    "question": "Was he conscious or unconscious?",
    "input_type": "button"
  },
  {
    "question": "Did the patient get any traumatism because\nof failing down?",
    "input_type": "button",
    "symptom_id": 66,
    "question_id": 300,
    "symptom_name": "Burns ",
    "input_type_data": [
      {
        "text": "Yes"
      },
      {
        "text": "Noo"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "question": "Does he have a cough or breathing difficulties?",
    "input_type": "button",
    "symptom_id": 66,
    "question_id": 301,
    "symptom_name": "Burns ",
    "input_type_data": [
      {
        "text": "Yes"
      },
      {
        "text": "Noo"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "question": "Does he have nausea or vomit?",
    "input_type": "button",
    "symptom_id": 66,
    "question_id": 302,
    "symptom_name": "Burns ",
    "input_type_data": [
      {
        "text": "Yes"
      },
      {
        "text": "Noo"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "question": "Does he was like fainting?",
    "input_type": "button",
    "symptom_id": 66,
    "question_id": 303,
    "symptom_name": "Burns ",
    "input_type_data": [
      {
        "text": "Yes"
      },
      {
        "text": "Noo"
      }
    ]
  }
 ]
}
]
```

My logic

```
for (str in symptomsData!![position].questions!!)
{
    var ans=str.question
    holder.question.text = ans
}
```

How should i for loop to get the questions in textview.I am able to get the questions array but printing only last value in textview.I want to print all the values in textview

Answer (score 0):

First create a local list of questions .Then you can use

```
val list = ArrayList<questions>()
//Add your current position questions to arraylist 

list.addall(symptomsData!![position].questions)
 for (i in questions. indices){
 //append your last question here 
                holder.question.text = questions[i].question 
            }
```

With above for loop , you will be able to get the question from the questions array . Then you  use string builder or append to get your final string .

And avoid using !!  . This may result in null pointer exception , if your array is null . Instead use ? .

Comment: questions.indices is my arraylist of questions??

Comment: Yeah . Create a array of questions . val quesArray = ArrayList<Questions>()

Comment: questions.indices .  is used to get the current index of the array . i,e value of i .

Comment: Plese correct me if i am wrong , you want to print every question from your question array ?

Comment: yes every question from the question array i want to print

Comment: Then this will help .

Comment: i passed the array to a custom Adapter that i created and then printed the values.